# PowerShell's input file changes and does not run. firewall

Tags: powershell

I didn't make it. https://lifestream.kr/90 (Original address)

I want to block a specific country ip.

Except for my country. Also, I want to block ip except for router ip Google dns.

China, Russia and North Korea. These three countries.

The old one works well.

But it doesn't work after swapping files.

`GeoIPCountryWhois.csv`=The file is old. Updates are no longer supported. a chargeable conversion

.

`GeoIPCountryWhois.csv`=original file(old) ,  `IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.CSV`=A new file I want to put in.

https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/docs/databases/city-and-country?lang=en#csv-databases
It became a paid service.=`GeoIPCountryWhois.csv`

https://download.ip2location.com/lite/ This is a free service.=`IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.CSV`

`GeoIPCountryWhois.csv`=The file works fine.

`IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.CSV`=But... this file doesn't work.

.

The files are different.

original file `GeoIPCountryWhois.csv`

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","16779264","16781311","CN","China"
```

.

Free version file `IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.CSV`

```
"0","16777215","-","-"
"16777216","16777471","US","United States of America"
"16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
"16779264","16781311","CN","China"
"16781312","16785407","JP","Japan"
```

So I can't apply the new file

`.\test.ps1`

```
#############Config#################
$countryCode="CN", "RU", "KP" #차단할 나라의 CountryCode
#$geoIPcvsPath="d:\IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.CSV"
$geoIPcvsPath="\IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.CSV"
$ruleName="blockCountry"
#############Config#################
 
 
$geoData=Import-Csv $geoIPcvsPath -header sIP, eIP, start, end, cc, cn |  where-object {$_.cc –in $countryCode}
$geoDataTotal=$geoData.Count
$remoteIP=""
 
 
######  룰이 있는 지 체크 ########
function ruleExistsChk ($ruleName)
{
    $fw=New-object -comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2; # http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2009/02/18/how-to-manage-the-windows-firewall-settings-with-powershell.aspx
    $RuleCHK=$fw.rules | where-object {$_.name –eq $ruleName}
    if(!$RuleCHK){
    #$deny_rule_name + " 룰이 생성되어 있지 않습니다."; exit;
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="$ruleName" localip=any dir=in action=block profile="any" interfacetype="any"
    }
}
######  룰이 있는 지 체크 ########
 
 
$count=1
foreach ($geoIP in $geoData)
{
    #$remoteIP+=@($geoIP.sIP+"-"+$geoIP.eIP+",") #배열로 저장.
     $remoteIP+=$geoIP.sIP+"-"+$geoIP.eIP+","
      
     #remoteAddr가 한개의 룰에 약 300개 이상이면 등록이 안됨. 안전하게 200으로 설정.
    if(($count%200) -eq 0)
    {
        $makeRuleName=$ruleName+$countryCode+$count
        ruleExistsChk($makeRuleName)
        netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=$makeRuleName new remoteip="$remoteIP"
        $remoteIP=""
    }elseif($geoDataTotal -eq $count){
        $makeRuleName=$ruleName+$countryCode+$count
        ruleExistsChk($makeRuleName)
        netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=$makeRuleName new remoteip="$remoteIP"
        $remoteIP=""
    }
 
     $count++
 
}
```

If you run it, nothing happens.

The command I ordered to register is not generated, but only the computer cursor appears.

`findstr /blv "# 0.0.0. 192.168.0.0/16 224.0.0.0/16 172.30. 192.168. 224.0. 168.126. 210.220. 219.250. 61.41. 1.214. 164.124. 203.248. 180.182. 94.140. 208.67. 1.1. 1.0. 8.8. 9.9. 149.112. 194.242. 185.222. 45.11. 10.0. 172.162"` I'd like to exclude some ip.

`https://mirror.dk.team.blue/firehol/ip2location_country/ip2location_country_kr.netset`
And I want to exclude Korean IP from the above ip. Because I am Korean in Seoul.. Because I can't use the internet if similar ip Korea is blocked.

There are three questions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following shows you to parse your new CSV file in a way that results in objects with the same properties as with the old file, with the help of [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```bash
# Helper function that converts a big-endian 32-bit value representing
# an IPv4 address into its string representation.
# E.g.:
#    ConvertTo-Ipv4FromBigEndian 16779263 # -> '1.0.7.255'
function ConvertTo-Ipv4FromBigEndian {
  param([uint32] $bigEndianIpv4)
  $byteArray = [BitConverter]::GetBytes($bigEndianIpv4)
  [Array]::Reverse($byteArray)
  ([IPAddress] [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($byteArray)).ToString()
}

# Note: Here I'm assuming that the input CSV file, IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.CSV,
#       is located in the *current* directory; adjust as needed.
$geoData = 
  Import-Csv -Header start,end,cc,cn IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.CSV |
  Select-Object @{ n='sIp'; e={ ConvertTo-Ipv4FromBigEndian $_.start } },
                @{ n='eIp'; e={ ConvertTo-Ipv4FromBigEndian $_.end } }, 
                *
```

Comment: sorry. I'm a `ps1` computer novice, so I can't complete the insert. Can't you post the finished product on the blog? No matter what I do, I don't know what I'm doing wrong from the start.

Comment: @krdondon, you should be able to adapt your solution based on the following: your My answer uses an _example_ input file name - `IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.CSV` - in the `Import-Csv` call, which looks for a file of that name in the _current directory_; you should replace it with `$geoIPcvsPath`, assuming that you've defined that variable to contain the actual path.

Comment: You are very kind to explain.
But I... I'm a computer beginner, so I don't understand from start to finish. for example.

Comment: I don't understand anything right now. If I had any understanding, I would have corrected it right now. I will only know when I see the finished product.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made you repeat the same thing. I'm so sorry. T^T

Comment: I empathize, @krdondon. but the potentially iterative step-by-step guidance you're looking for is beyond [the mandate of this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), though perhaps [this information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/45375) helps. If not, there are other forums out there that provide what you need, or perhaps a colleague can help you.

Comment: Okay. Since I don't know anyone... it's hard to find a developer who can fix it. Thank you for your hard work.